# Atualização de quantidade com update (Carrinho de compras)

Tags: php

Estou criando um carrinho de compras. Este carrinho é sem usuário e senha, ou seja, ele usa apenas a sessão do próprio carrinho que é criado quando o usuário escolhe o produto. Após o cliente escolher o produto e clicar em "IR PARA CHECKOUT", o sistema faz um inserção no banco de dados dos produtos que ele escolheu (nome_produto; descrição e valor) e o código do pedido se torna a sessão do cliente. Logo, eu consigo fazer uma busca no banco de dados da sessão criada. O Código da sessão também é inerido no banco de dados, para que eu consiga fazer a busca.

Código da inserção no banco de dados:

```
                @$produto = $_POST['produto'];
                  if(isset($produto)) {
                      foreach ($produto as $reck) {
                        $consultaProduto = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = '$reck'");
                        while($exibeProdutos = $consultaProduto->fetch_assoc()){
                            $nome_produto = $exibeProdutos['nome_produto'];
                            $valor_produto = $exibeProdutos['valor'];
                            $descricao = $exibeProdutos['descricao_produto'];
                            $imagem = $exibeProdutos['imagem_produto'];
                            $pedidoReck = "200";
                            $horarioReck = date("h:i:s");
                            $pedidoLokos = "{$pedidoReck}{$horarioReck}";
                            $insereProduto = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO carrinho (numeroPedido, produto, descricao, valor) values ('$pedidoLokos','$nome_produto','$descricao','$valor_produto')");
                            $_SESSION['numero_pedido'] = $pedidoLokos;
                           /* if($insereProduto){
                              echo "Produto inserido";
                            }else{
                              echo "Produto não inserido". mysqli_error($conexao);
                            }*/

                          }
                        }

                        header("Location: carrinho.php");

                      } /*Fecha produto*/
```

Após isso, o cliente/usuário é redirecionado para o carrinho.php. Nele, eu faço a consulta se a sessão está criada e se estiver e ela for igual ao do inserido no banco de dados, ela ira trazer os produtos lá cadastrado.

Código completo do carrinho:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="mad-products mad-product-small">

                      <?php
                         session_start();
                          header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                          date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
                          $conexao = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxxx","cardapio_cheirinbao","d#m14e4E","cardapio_cheirinbao");

                          if(!$conexao){

                            echo "Impossível se conectar ao banco de dados";
                            exit;
                          } 
                           $pedidoLokos = $_SESSION['numero_pedido'];
                            $consultaProduto = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM carrinho WHERE numeroPedido = '$pedidoLokos'");
                            $valorTotal = 0; 
                            while($exibeProdutos = $consultaProduto->fetch_assoc()){
                                $nome_produto = $exibeProdutos['produto'];
                                $valor_produto = $exibeProdutos['valor'];
                                $valorVirgula = str_replace('.', ',', $valor_produto);
                                $valorTotal += $valor_produto;
                                $descricao = $exibeProdutos['descricao_produto'];
                                $imagem = $exibeProdutos['imagem_produto'];
                                $id = $exibeProdutos['id'];
                                $quan = $exibeProdutos['quantidade'];
?>
                      <div class="mad-col">
                        <!-- Product -->
                        <div class="mad-product">
                       <a href="excluirproduto.php?a=<?=$id?>" class="mad-close-item2"><i style="color:red;" class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                          <a href="#" class="mad-product-image">

                            <?php

                            if($imagem){

                              echo "<img style='width:80px; height:80px;'' src='https://boahost.com.br/cheiro/adm/imagens/produtos/$imagem' alt=''>";

                            }else{

                            echo "";
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="quantity">
                          <input type="text" value="1" readonly="" name="quantidade_produto">
                          <button type="button" class="qty-plus"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></button>
                          <button type="button" class="qty-minus"><i class="fas fa-minus fa-2x"></i></button>
                        </div>
                            
                          </a>
                          <!-- product-info -->
                          <div class="mad-product-description">
                            

                            <a href="#" class="mad-product-title mad-link"><input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>" name="id_produto"><?=$nome_produto;?> <sup style="color:#7a7879"> (<?=$quan;?>x)</a>
                           
                            <span class="mad-product-price">R$ <?=$valorVirgula;?></span>
                          </div>
                          <!--/ product-info -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- End of Product -->
                      </div>

<?php

                            }

                      ?>



                    </div>
                    <div class="sc-footer">
                        <div class="subtotal">Total do pedido: <span>R$  <?php echo number_format($valorTotal, 2, ',', ' '); ?></span> <span style="float:right;"><a href="excluir.php"> <i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i> Limpar Carrinho </a> </span></div>
                        <button class="btn w-100"><span>Finalizar Pedido <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-2x"></i> </span> <i><img src="https://velikorodnov.com/html/steakbreak_svg_icons/short_arrow_right.svg" alt="" class="svg"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

</form>
```

Observem que em cada produto (no carrrinho.php ), existe um campo de quantidade para que o cliente/usuário possa aumentar a quantidade:

```
 <div class="quantity">
                      <input type="text" value="1" readonly="" name="quantidade_produto">
                      <button type="button" class="qty-plus"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></button>
                      <button type="button" class="qty-minus"><i class="fas fa-minus fa-2x"></i></button>
                    </div>
```

Foi criado um SCRIPT para quando o cliente/usuário adicionar aumentar a quantidade o sistema faça um UPDATE lá na tabela dos valores e também da quantidade e apresente na tela após fazer essa atualização. Veja:

```
<?php 



@$id_produto = $_POST['id_produto'];
@$quantidade = $_POST['quantidade_produto'];

if(isset($id_produto)):

$consultaProduto = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM carrinho WHERE id = '$id_produto' AND numeroPedido = '$pedidoLokos'");
$atualizaValor = $consultaProduto->fetch_assoc();
$valorBanco = $atualizaValor['valor'];

$valorReal = $valorBanco * $quantidade;


$atualizaProduto = $conexao->query("UPDATE carrinho SET valor = '{$valorReal}', quantidade = '{$quantidade}' WHERE id = '{$id_produto}' AND numeroPedido = '{$pedidoLokos}'");

if($atualizaProduto){
  echo "Feito";
}else{
  echo "Desfeito";
}

endif;



?>
```

Contudo, quando o sistema só está fazendo a atualização do último produto.  Por exemplo: Quando eu seleciono 2 produtos, ele trás corretamente no carrinho.php. Quando eu clico na quantidade no ULTIMO produto (aumento a quantidade) e clico em "FINALIZAR PEDIDO" ele faz a alteração normalmente. Porém, quando eu tento fazer a alteração em outros produtos tirando o último ele dá a mensagem que foi feito com sucesso, mas não atualiza. Veja a foto:

[image: Aumento da quantidade somente no último produto]

Desta forma, eu não estou conseguindo achar uma solução para que o programa consiga fazer a atualização também em outros produtos além do último. Como eu posso fazer? Obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você não está identificando os produtos que devem ter as quantidades alteradas quando o botão é pressionado.

Uma sugestão de solução seria alterar os componentes para os botões plus e minus usando um link como fez para a remoção. Por exemplo, substituir os dois buttons pelas linhas a seguir

```
<a href="alterarquantidade.php?a=<?=$id?>&o=plus" class="qty-plus"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></a>

<a href="alterarquantidade.php?a=<?=$id?>&o=minus" class="qty-plus"><i class="fas fa-minus fa-2x"></i></a>
```

**Note**

1. que nelas suponho a criação do script `alteraquantidade.php`, específico para tratar o aumento ou redução da quantidade de produtos no carrinho, mesma estratégia que você utilizou para remover. E também simulo a passagem do parâmetro `o` (pensei em operação) passando se a ação é de adição ou subtração (plu ou minus).
2. que estou usando a abordagem de a cada clique o script ser chamado e nele você deverá redirecionar para o carregamento do carrinho novamente, como já acontece com sua estratégia atual, para não realizar o refresh de página seria necessário utilizar AJAX.

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida, como eu poderia fazer para o PLUS virar um número para se multiplicar?

Comment: Uma ideia seria alterar o campo de quantidade para que permita ao usuário digitar nele (input text) e ao invés de minus e plus, colocar somente um botão alterar qtde